# SQL Server query for finding duplicate rows from identical tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about finding identical rows from one table to another. I have a table for users to ask for information. So with that the query will be ran against another table. Both tables are identical except for the ID columns.

The ID columns are not involved in the query except for the

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM searchTable 
ORDER BY searchid DESC
```

part.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM searchTable 
ORDER BY searchid DESC(SELECT A.column1, A.column2,..............
                       FROM dbo.searchTable A
                       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM realTable B 
                                     WHERE A.Column1 = B.Column1 
                                       AND A.Column2 = B.Column2,
                                       .......
                                       AND A.lastColumn = B.lastColumn))
```

What I get when running the query is the last entered query from the query table, which is correct, but I get all the rows listed from the `realTable` as if everything after `WHERE EXISTS` is pointless. What I need is the single row query from the `queryTable` to list all the rows that are identical to it from the `realTable`. Not all the rows the `realTable` has.

Comment: Not sure if understand the question. If you change places of "realTable" and "queryTable" - will it solve the problem? Can you provide some more details and maybe desired output?

Comment: No one can debug a query that is not posted. And your code contradicts your stated results. The queries select from searchTable only - both of them. It is impossible to get "all rows listed from the realTable".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inner join` instead of `exists`.

```
select B.* from searchTable A
inner join realTable B
on A.Column1 = B.Column1
and A.Column2 = B.Column2
.
.
.
```

It will return all the records in your `realTable` which have identical columns with your `searchTable`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work the way I needed by understanding the logic in the last suggestion.

It looks like this.

DECLARE @searchID int = (SELECT MAX(searchID) FROM searchTable)

SELECT Column1, Column2.............LastColumn FROM realTable B

WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM searchTable A WHERE searchID = @searchID AND A.Column1=B.Column1 AND A.Column2=B.Column2................A.LastColumn=B.LastColumn)

Now the last search in the searchTable will give me all the rows in the realTable that match that search.